# CLISP : Check if two elements are in order one after another in a list

Tags: list, lisp

I have a list

```
 L=(1 j 3 k 4 h 5 n 6 w)
```

I need to do a function Verify that will verify if the first atom is before the 2nd.
I want to verify this:

```
> Verify(3 k)
```

result should return

```
> T
```

// because atom '3' is before atom 'k'

And in this case :

```
>Verify(h 4)
```

result should return

```
> NIL
```

// because atom 'h' is after atom '4'

I have to check position of each element and compare positions

Comment: The syntax in this question doesn't look like Lisp. What interpreter are you using?

Comment: @Óscar López this is not a LISP syntax, it's a kind of pseudo-code i used to explain what i want to do

Comment: Good. In my answer I tried to keep it neutral, follow the indications in the comments and you should be able to find a solution all by yourself. Sorry I can't give you a straight answer, but it's homework...

Comment: @Óscar López  I have to do this function in Common LISP

Comment: what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What dialect of Lisp are you using? Here are some pointers on how to derive a solution, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (verify lst a b)
        ; what happens if there's only one element left in the list?
  (cond ((null? (cdr lst)) <???>)
        ; how do we check if the current element is equal to the `a` parameter
        ; and the next element is equal to the `b` parameter?
        (<???> T)
        ; how do we continue traversing the rest of the list?
        (else (verify <???> a b))))

;;; tests

(define lst '(1 j 3 k 4 h 5 n 6 w))

(verify lst 3 'k)
> T
(verify lst 'h '4)
> F
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-liner in Common Lisp:

```
(defun verify (list a b)
  (member b (member a list)))
```

Note it does not return T or NIL, but a "generalized boolean" (any value other than `nil` is true). This is a fundamental concept in Lisp:

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_g.htm#generalized_boolean

This also assumes that "before" means "anywhere before". Your homework problem looks like it may be about "immediately before". It should be easy to modify.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work                               (defun Verify (list a b)
(member b (Member a list)))

(SetQ List '(1 3 a r 5 6 d y))
(Verify List 'r 5)   
Result : Break 24 [26]> 
(5 6 D Y)

Comment: `(5 6 D Y)` is a true result because it is an object different from `nil`. This is the "generalized boolean" concept that I refer to in the answer. Generalized booelan means that for instance you can do this `(if (verify list 'r 5) (format t "yes, it verified true!~%"))`. The `(5 6 D Y)` object will be treated by `if` as a true so the `format` is evaluated.  This is how boolean values are handled in a lot of Lisp code; you'd be wasting effort converting them to strictly `t` and `nil`.

Comment: You can turn a generalized boolean into strictly `t` and `nil` with an extra `if` around it like this: `(if generalized-boolean-expression t)`.  If the expression yields true, then produce `t`. (Otherwise produce `nil`: that is implicit if there is no third argument to `if`).

Comment: I tried but it always give NIL                                  (defun Verify (list a b)
(member b (Member a list)))

(SetQ List '(1 3 a r 5 6 d y))
(if (Verify List 1 3)(format t "yes, it verified true!~%"))