# CLISP: Ordering a list depending on the order of elements in another

Tags: list, lisp

I have a list

```
(SetQ L '(1 j 3 k 4 h 5 n 6 w))
```

I have to do a function Order that has a list with 'n' atoms at entry, it must check if each atom of that list is contained in list L and order them according to the order specified in list L, if the atom is not part of the list L then the result will be displayed

```
(Defun Order lst)

(SetQ L2'(w o 5 j 3))
```

I want to verify this:

```
(Order L2)
```

result should return:

```
(J 3 5 W)
```

Comment: Should this be tagged "homework"? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Earlier, you asked this question:

[CLISP : Check if two elements are in order one after another in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303736/clisp-check-if-two-elements-are-in-order-one-after-another-in-a-list)

This function is related to the problem because it can be used as a comparison function in a call to the standard Lisp function `sort`.

The Lisp function `intersection` can produce a list which contains only those elements of one list which appear in another. This is a set operation, so it may squash duplicates; another way is to use `remove-if-not` where the test predicate is a lambda function which uses `member` to express the idea "remove all elements of this list which are not members of that other list".